# Selecting values inside array in jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE country (
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    name        VARCHAR(50),
    extra_info  JSONB
);
 
INSERT INTO country(id,extra_info)
VALUES (1, '{ "name" : "France", "population" : "65000000", "flag_colours": ["red", "blue","white"]}');
 
INSERT INTO country(id,extra_info)
VALUES (2, '{ "name": "Spain", "population" : "47000000", "borders": ["Portugal", "France"] }');

SELECT extra_info->>'name' as Name, extra_info->>'population' as Population
FROM country
```

I would like to select id and extra info

```
SELECT id,extra_info->>'population' as Population,extra_info->'flag_colours'->>1 as colors
FROM country
```

This query shows only id,population but the flag_colors is null.

I also would like to use flag_colors in a condition

```
SELECT extra_info->>'population' as Population FROM country where extra_info->'flag_colours'->>0
```

i get this error

```
ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text
LINE 1: ...o->>'population' as Population FROM country where extra_info...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42804
Character: 67
```

How can i fix the two queries?

Comment: Misspelling: `flag_colours` in the data vs `flag_colors` in the query

Comment: "*I also would like to use flag_colors in a condition*" - what should the condition filter for? For flag_colors to exist in the json? For the first flag color to be red? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, flag colour to be red. Thats the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote my query this way

```
SELECT *
FROM country
WHERE (extra_info -> 'flag_colours') ? 'red' and (extra_info -> 'flag_colours') ? 'white'
```

Many thanks to [alt-f4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11271048/alt-f4)

updated answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62858683/492293